# Calling 3 AsynTask at a time keeps application busy

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have 3 `AsynTask` in my application. And I want to call all that at a time or one by one and that is `OnCreate()`.

But As I have checked, after execution of first `AsynTask`, Application keeps busy and does not fire another 2 `AsynTask`.
I have also tried calling `AsynTask` on another `AsynTask`'s `OnPostExecute()` but no result.
How to prevent this problem ? I am binding `Spinner` by using this method. It is working fine individually and gives fast response.

**Sample Code:**

```
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            new Task1.execute();
            new Task2.execute();
            new Task3.execute();
    }
```

Comment: can you post the sample code??

Comment: are you doing too much work in `onPreExecute()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of above solutions worked for me.
Finally, I have solved this problem.
I call second `AsynTask()` on another `AsynTask()`'s on `OnPostExecute()` and I am surprised. :)

Answer (score 0):

As of 3.0, AsyncTasks all execute on one thread, one after another.  If you want to run them at the same time, use `executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params)` instead of `execute()`.

Comment: I have tried this but It was taking long time and then also I dint stop. I also dnt have any problem to call it one by one.